# Make vertical scrollbar always visible within a DIV

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'd like the scrollbar within my "article" DIV to be always visible. I tried the code below but without success (scrollbar only shows up when I start scrolling down). I'm using safari latest version. Thanks

```
.article {
    float: right;
    text-align:justify;
    width: 400px;
    height: 450px;
    padding: 60px 82px 49px 82px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
    margin-top: 90px;
    background: #fff;
    /* max-width: 25%; */
    overflow:scroll; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
overflow-y: scroll !important;
```

It's used to cover IE errors, but might give it a shot. Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Just tried with fireworks and it works OK so I guess this is a Safari issue. Will consider using a jquery scrollbar plugin then....